# Angular cli 7 component do not render html on custom tag call

Tags: angular-cli, angular7

I have a problem with `angular-cli 7`. 
I build a new project with `cli` command lines, I create a new component with command line too and when I call this new component with his custom html tag in app.component.html. NOTHING is displaying.

I made many researches, changed angular version, change OS, change browser, try different different configurations. I have no errors in my console and no html render. I don't understand WHY?

```
/////////////////app.component.html 
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
  <img width="300" alt="Angular Logo" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAyNTAgMjUwIj4KICAgIDxwYXRoIGZpbGw9IiNERDAwMzEiIGQ9Ik0xMjUgMzBMMzEuOSA2My4ybDE0LjIgMTIzLjFMMTI1IDIzMGw3OC45LTQzLjcgMTQuMi0xMjMuMXoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCBmaWxsPSIjQzMwMDJGIiBkPSJNMTI1IDMwdjIyLjItLjFWMjMwbDc4LjktNDMuNyAxNC4yLTEyMy4xTDEyNSAzMHoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCAgZmlsbD0iI0ZGRkZGRiIgZD0iTTEyNSA1Mi4xTDY2LjggMTgyLjZoMjEuN2wxMS43LTI5LjJoNDkuNGwxMS43IDI5LjJIMTgzTDEyNSA1Mi4xem0xNyA4My4zaC0zNGwxNy00MC45IDE3IDQwLjl6IiAvPgogIDwvc3ZnPg==">
</div>
<h2>Here are some links to help you start: </h2>
<ul>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://angular.io/tutorial">Tour of Heroes</a></h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://angular.io/cli">CLI Documentation</a></h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://blog.angular.io/">Angular blog</a></h2>
  </li>
</ul>
<maison></maison>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

////////////app.module.ts

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BoiteComponent } from './boite/boite.component';
import { MaisonComponent } from './maison.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    BoiteComponent,
    MaisonComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  exports:[
    BoiteComponent,
    MaisonComponent
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]

})
export class AppModule { 

}
```

I would like to just use the BASCIS of angular and be able to call a component in an other... now this do not work and i don't understand why ... 
I did not code with angular since some month ago, so maybe i forgot something simple but i m on this problem since HOURES so i ask your help please, thanks

Comment: can you please provide mansion.component code also so we can check.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i finded the solution, i will answer to my own question. I did not put the component code becose i did not changed any thing on it.

Answer (score -1):

OK... Its always when you ask the question that you find the answer ^^
SOLUTION : when you give a name for you component like : hello
When you call it on your app, you dont call  ( this do not work)

> > you have to call

If this answer can help for other and let them win some TIME ... :) ;)